# Proof of surjectivity without formula for the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm reading an entry-level textbook and the following is one of the exercises given:

> Two functions are given: $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$. furthermore it is given that $fg=\operatorname{id}_Y$ and $gf=\operatorname{id}_X$.
>
> Now one should prove that $f$ is surjective.
>
> $x \in X$, $y \in Y$

One idea is:
to choose x = g(y) so f(x)=f(g(y)) and with IDy given above it follows that f(x)=y q.e.d.
But I think this isn't valid, because I need g to be a surjection for this and it is not given that it is one.

Another idea is:
x=g(f(x)) I can say so because of the IDx relation given.
From that it follows that f(x)=f(g(f(x))) which transforms to f(x)=y with the IDy relation given.

But once again I think that that when moving from f(g(f(x))) to y I'm assuming that  the innermost f(x) is a surjection, so this would be kind of circular reasoning.

I'm really stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should say what $x$ and $y$ are; this is where your confusion comes from. Is $x$ given, and are you defining $y$ by $x = g(y)$, or is it the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y\in Y$, then $y=f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)$. In particular, $y$ belongs to range of $f$.

Comment: In particular, we don't need to know that $gf = \mathbf{id}_X$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you very much for your solution and for your nice edit of my question! If I understand it right, what you've written down is $id_{y}$ which is given. Since it's the identity it's trivial that f(...) covers the whole range of y, so no further calculations are necessary. Right?

Comment: Since I don't know what $id_y$ is, I can't agree or disagree with you. I did one and only one thing: I proved that every $y\in Y$ belongs to the range of $f$ (that is, it is of the form $f(x)$, for some $x\in X$). That is exatly what “$f$ is surjective” means.